# Find the sum of the series $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+...-(2n)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+...-(2n)^2$$

I tried rewriting it as $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n}-1^{n+1}(r^2)$$ but it didn't help.

Also, looked at re-arranging as $$1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+...+(2n-1)^2$$ and $$-2^2-4-6^2-8^2-...-(2n)^2$$

Still couldn't get to the given answer of $-n(2n+1)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$(2n-1)^2-(2n)^2=1-4n,$$
and therefore your sum is equal to
$$\underbrace{(1+1+\ldots+1)}_{n\;\mathrm{times}}-4\left(1+2+\ldots+n\right)=n-4\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=-n(2n+1).$$
The only thing one needs to know is the arithmetic progression sum.

Comment: where does the $n$ at the start of the second line come from please?

Comment: @GezBishop It comes from $1$ in $1-4n$, which appears $n$ times. I have edited the answer to explain this.

Comment: I see, is that the same as in $\sum_{r=1}^n1=1+1+1+...+1=n$? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: We have $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1).$$

Hint 2: Note that 
$$1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots-(2n)^2=1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n)^2-2(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2)$$
$$
=1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2-2^3(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k^2-8\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2.$$

Comment: In Hint 2, how do you get from the LHS to the RHS, please?

Comment: Wouldn't $n_1=1^2-2(2(1))^2=-4,n_2=2^2-2(2(2))^2=-48,...$ on that RHS?

Comment: @Gez What are you talking about? Do you disagree with $a-b+c-d=(a+b+c+d)-2(b+d)$ for example?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$1^2 - 2^2 + \ldots + (2n-1)^2 - (2n)^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + (2n)^2 - 8 (1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$${ 1 }^{ 2 }-{ 2 }^{ 2 }=-\left( 1+2 \right) \\ { 3 }^{ 2 }-{ 4 }^{ 2 }=-\left( 3+4 \right) \\ { 5 }^{ 2 }-{ 6 }^{ 2 }=-\left( 5+6 \right) \\ \vdots \\ { \left( 2n-1 \right)  }^{ 2 }-{ \left( 2n \right)  }^{ 2 }=-\left( 2n-1+2n \right) $$

Sum up, you get the answer that O.L. has written.